# iOS twitter API single User oAuth

Tags: objective-c, ios, twitter

I'm looking to make the move from twitter 1 api to 1.1 and I understand the need to use oAuth to authenticate my requests.

All my app does at present is retrieve a set user's time line and displays that to the app user.

I dont want the user to have to sign in to twitter to view the user's timeline.
The usage-restrictions are not an issue (15 per 15 minutes)

Can someone explain to me where to go from here, I want to keep my deployment target at 4.3 and not having much look finding documentation on twitter iOS single User OAUTH.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to resolve this using 'ABOAuthCore' library available on Github.. This created the relevant header value for me and was used as such:

```
NSString *authorizationHeader = OAuthorizationHeader(newsURL,
                                                     @"GET",
                                                     postBody,
                                                    KConsumerKey, 
                                                     KConsumerSecret,
                                                     KAccessToken, 
                                                     KAccessTokenSecret); 

[request setValue:authorizationHeader forHTTPHeaderField:@"Authorization"];
```

Answer (score 0):

After creating the app ID at [dev.twitter.com](http://dev.twitter.com), in the "details" tab there will be a place to create a single user token. Use this in place of the user's token and token secret.

[image]

I recommend only doing this on a read-only access level.

Comment: not seeing the single user token or the ability to create one? i have created the app and have all the tokens etc for use with oAuth?

Comment: @burrows111 Sorry, just realised it doesn't seem to be called single user token there but it's still the same thing. I've added a picture to my answer.

Comment: ok thanks, thats got me going... now to stick it into iOS... have you any experience in that? if you have any advice that would be great. thanks:)

Comment: How are you doing oAuth atm (without the single user token) or are have you not implemented it at all yet?

Comment: not at all, im moving from version 1 of the api where i could just call the api and parse the returned json

Comment: @burrows111 Okay, got you. Using any networking library or are you using the built in NSURLConnection and co?

Comment: Ah, Stack Overflow keeps clearing my edits, I'll post up a solution tomorrow.